# Redirect of specific words in URL ahead of website migration

Tags: redirect, 404-error, migration

I'm migrating my website from Squarespace to WordPress and wondering if I can get ahead of the one thousand+ 404s I'll hit by setting up something to redirect specific keywords to remove them.

###### The old site will have links like:

```
website.com/aritcles/abc123
website.com/news/news123
website.com/reviews/likeit123
```

###### On the new website, they'll be:

```
website.com/abc123
website.com/news123
webstie.com/likeit123
```

Is there something I can do to remove the keywords `news`, `reviews` and `articles` and get a redirect system in place ahead of moving the domain?

Comment: You are keeping the names, right? I suppose the missing `e` and `3` in website.com/aritcle/abc12 -> website.com/abc**e**12**3** is a typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry just spelling mistakes on my end.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this is by using `mod_rewrite`.

Open your `.htaccess` file and add this code **before** the `# BEGIN WordPress` line:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aritcles/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^reviews/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

How will the squarespace database be imported to WordPress if the table is not compatible?

What ever the WP permalink configuration is within **Settings**, your posts should default to that URL format. If you select **Custom Structure** and set `/%postname%/` only, that is what you get after the domain.

If that fails and you need to program the task, there may be plugins available for the process, however if you want to write code, using the built-in method `add_rewrite_rule` would be simpler.

**Example** - not tested! See a rewrite rule article at https://brightminded.com/blog/mastering-wordpress-rewrite-rules/

action hook within theme's `functions.php` or a plugin you create

```php
add_action('init', function() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^reviews/(.*)$','index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]','top');
});
```

You will need to update the rules table by **Settings > Permalinks > save changes**